# How do I install GMSH?

Tags: software-installation, package-management

I am trying to install Gmsh in 12.04 x64:

```
xxx@sjb-linux:/320/installslinux/gmsh$ sudo apt-get install gmsh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gmsh : Depends: libmed1 (>= 3.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
xxx@sjb-linux:/320/installslinux/gmsh$
```

I have now tried all the advice I could get

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get clean
```

with no success, these commands report absolutely no problem.

I'll appreciate help.

Comment: mention ubuntu version and System architecture like is it 32 bit or 64..

Answer (score 1):

**gmsh** won't install because **libmed1** won't install either. The problem is that there is a conflict with different versions of package **libhdf5**.

So in order to fix it

- Open synaptic and searched for **libhdf5**
- Then install **libhdf5-openmpi-1.8.4**, this will remove some of the libhdf5 packages and IIRC some octave-3.2 packages too.

After that I went on to install **libmed1** and once that was done I was finally able to install **gmsh**.

So far I haven't had any further problems related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that `gmsh` having dependencies those having their own dependencies. So include the `not going to be installed` package to the main installation list.

```
sudo apt-get install gmsh libmed1
```